# Facebook Login Not Working on Realm Object Server

Tags: android, facebook, realm

I followed the Realm Object Server documentation to enable Facebook login, as shown in the index.ts code below.

```
import { BasicServer } from 'realm-object-server'
import * as path from 'path'
import {FacebookAuthProvider} from "../node_modules/realm-object-server/dist/auth/facebook/FacebookAuthProvider"
import {GoogleAuthProvider from "../node_modules/realm-object-server/dist/auth/facebook/GoogleAuthProvider"


const server = new BasicServer()
const RealmObjectServer = require('realm-object-server');
const path = require('path');


const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider({
    clientId: '898585320567-fi5bqf298e9kiq7fdv56g46i7i5s38nn.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});

const facebookProvider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
server.start({
        // This is the location where ROS will store its runtime data
        dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),


     authProviders: [ facebookProvider ],[ googleProvider ],
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Realm Object Server was started on ${server.address}`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error starting Realm Object Server: ${err.message}`)
    })
```

I created a Facebook app and added Facebook login to my Android and the Facebook login works because I am able to login to Facebook successfully, notice how the login button below now shows Log out.

[image]

How I keep getting the same error message *"Invalid Parameters(601) Your Request did not validate.*  The authentication with Facebooks works fine

Is there any step I am missing, do we still need to update configuration.yaml in Real Object Server 2.x

Comment: My guess is that you're using a different version of the protocol between the client and server. I don't think that you need the `configuration.yaml` anymore for 2.x. Which version of ROS & Realm Java are you using?